# proxy servers like SQUID

Tags: filter, nginx, squid

are there others proxy servers like SQUID? I have seen nginx and others, but they seem not work with filter content, block urls, domains, etc.

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Proxy-Servers

```
Apache HTTP Server
Apache Traffic Server - high-performance open-source HTTP proxy server.
lighttpd - open-source web server, optimized for speed-critical environments.
Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway, (ISA), forward and reverse caching proxy and firewall.
Nginx - lightweight, high-performance web server, reverse proxy and e-mail proxy (IMAP/POP3).
Polipo - lightweight pipelining, multiplexing, forwarding and caching proxy, SOCKS proxy and daemon.
Pound reverse proxy.
Privoxy - privacy enhancing proxy.
Squid cache - a proxy server and web cache daemon.
Tinyproxy - a fast and small HTTP proxy server daemon, which supports reverse proxying and transparent proxying.
TriangleBoy - an anonymizing proxy service.
Varnish - a performance-focused open source reverse proxy.
WinGate - multi-protocol forward/reverse/caching/intercepting proxy and packet firewall / NAT for Windows platforms.
Ziproxy - lightweight forwarding, non-caching, HTTP proxy for traffic optimization.
SuffixProxy - open-source HTTP-Suffix proxy server. Easy to use.
Glype - A free php based web proxy script. Easy to setup a proxy on a webserver quickly.
GeoEdge - A professional proxy server provider with 102 locations worldwide.
```